# Apps script: Paste filtered range to the next empty row in specific column

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I would like to create a code which copies a filtered column and pastes the whole column to the next available row in another sheet. The code below works however pastes the range in a loop until the end of the spreadsheet. How can I paste it just once?
I could not find an answer myself.
I would much appreciate your help!

```
function CopyFilter() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MASTER"); 
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
Logger.log("VALUES "+values.length);

var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
.whenNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo(1)
.build();

var range = sheet.getFilter()
.setColumnFilterCriteria(52, criteria)
.getRange();   
range.getValues();

var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("DL CSV OUTPUT");
sheet.getRange("AZ4:AZ").copyTo(sheet2.getRange(2,41,sheet2.getLastRow()+1), {contentsOnly:true});

sheet.getFilter().remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the copy method. Simply select the range you are interested in, then get a range (of same size - very important) in the target sheet and set all values at once.

EXAMPLE:

```
const valuesToCopy = sheet.getRange("AZ4:AZ").getValues();
sheet2.getRange(2,3,valuesToCopy.length).setValues(valuesToCopy);
```

And no need to worry about:  `{contentsOnly:true}`
Since the above method does not bring over any formatting.

#### Reference:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: They could also use `copyTo` if they use `Range.getNumRows()` instead of `getLastRow()` as the third parameter of the `getRange`.